# Building forms dynamically in React using Symfony Forms

Tags: json, reactjs, symfony4

My application uses Symfony for backend and React for front end. Is there a way dynamically build form in React by converting Symfony form into react forms? Rendering Symfony form in React app?

Comment: not sure why someone downvoted this... I'm looking for the same answer

Answer (score 3):

check

https://github.com/Limenius/LiformBundle

https://github.com/Limenius/liform-react

https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor

Hope this is what you asking form.